# Good text on Differential manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, book-recommendation, smooth-manifolds

I am new in field of topology.I am finding a good self readable text on differential 
manifolds.

Comment: you can try "INTRODUCTION TO SMOOTH MANIFOLDS" -JOHN LEE

Comment: prerequisites to read this book i am 3rd year engineering undergrad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John M. Lee

This is the standard, comprehensive textbook suitable for self-study. I strongly recommend you to try this.

Comment: Spivak's "Differential Geometry, Vol. 1" complements Lee nicely!

Comment: prerequisites to read this book i am 3rd year engineering undergrad